# Can I use 2 usb NES contollers at the same time?

Tags: controllers, emulation, nes

Is it possible to use 2 NES controllers with the USB adapters on my windows computers?  If so, how?  Thanks.

Comment: To play 2 player games

Answer (score 1):

You just plug them in at the same time.  Windows is suppose to be able to tell them apart.  You may have to bind the keys in the game.